# Navigation based application table view frame

Tags: uitableview, navigation, frame

I've used the navigation based application template in xcode, the default for this template is to set the table view to fill the screen however I would like to have the table view fill a frame smaller the the screen.

Here's the code it works initially however if a row is selected from the table and the user goes to the next screen when they press back the table view fills the screen rather than the frame.

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // set the frame size
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
    frame = CGRectMake(16.0, 36.0, 254.0, 350.0);
    self.tableView.frame = frame;

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's your controller type ? If it is uitableviewcontroller then it will systematically resize, it has to be a plain uiviewcontroller. For this type of small table I ususally use a simple uiview on the background an put a uitbaleview inside.

Comment: Hi thanks, yeah it's a uitableviewcontroller, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the class name to UIViewController and add an IBOutlet

```
@interface mycontroller : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;
    ....
}
```

In IB delete the table, create a UIView that you link to the controller's view outlet. Then create a table view that you place as a subview of the view. This one will keep its size. Set its outlet to tableView, set your controller as delegate and datasource. You then just need to implement the methods for the table view (numberOfSections..., numberOfRows..., cellForRow...) the same as in your current controler.

Comment: Im trying to do the same for a second level view controller, so i've changed the class name to UIViewController rather than UITableViewController and added an IBOutlet, however i have no xib file for the second level view controller so am a bit stuck. I've tried creating a new xib added a View Controller and chosen the class for the the View Controller and added the Table View and linked the outlets, but i'm not sure what the File's Owner class is as it just says NSObject and is linked to nothing. So when i run the app it crashes. Any ideas?

Comment: In IB you can set/change the file's owner class : select file's owner, open the identity inspector (alt-cmd-3), the pane on the right appears and you type in your class name.

Comment: Ok i did that, now in my list of objects I have a view controller > view > table view, is that what i need? Also what class shall i choose for the view controller and should i link my table view data source and delegate to the view controller or the file owner, this is the part i'm confused about.

Comment: When creating a new controller like this you don't need to put it into IB. Try creating one by using the file template library / add uiviewcontroller subclass it will come with the right IB structure - controller is the file owner, no other controller in the IB pane, just the view and subviews. Now the error message is completely different, it says you're calling initWithStyle on  CategoryOneController and this method doesn't exist. Also I expected to see 2 xibs on the screenshots as you mentioned 2 table view, I hope it's ok.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?80b2ka1bacypn74 here's a copy of the app, if you don't mind having a look at it, i'd really appreciate it. The first table view i have managed to fit in a frame, now i am trying to get the second table view into a frame too.

Comment: OK the initial part is a bit tricky as the controller is declared in the xib, you cannot do the trick with the table view inside this xib. You can create a separate xib where you define the view and the table view, then indicate in the inspector that this controller is loaded from another xib. For your second view controller, you don't have a xib, so you can handle it all in code in the viewdidload method. But again starting point is not to use UITableViewController as this one creates the table and sets it full screen.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5626/discussion-between-gregory-and-sami)